# How to get the same window.innerWidth regardless of the zoom level so my responsive layout won't change while zooming?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, viewport

I've built my app using `react`and `styled-components`. It's all client-side rendered and routed.

All my responsive layout is based on the `window.innerWidth` value and I do lots of:

```
const MyComponent_DIV = styled.div`
  width: ${props => props.isMobile ? "200px" : "400px"};
`;

const [windowWidth,setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

... some code

return (
  <MyComponent_DIV
    isMobile={windowWidth <= 768}
  />
);
```

**NOTE:** I also attach a **resize event listener**, so my app is responsive to `resize` events. So far so good.

```
function handleResize() {
  console.log("FROM RESIZE: " + window.innerWidth);  // I CAN SEE THIS VALUE CHANGING WHEN ZOOMING IN AND OUT
  setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
}
```

But the weird thing, at least to me, is when I found out that **changing the browser ZOOM level (on desktop and mobile) affects the `window.innerWidth` value.** And it also fires the `resize` event.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- Be responsive to resize events, but not to "ZOOM events"
- When user changes the zoom level, I want my layout to remain the same and show scroll bar when zoomed in.
- Basically I want the zoom to work normally like a zoom and not trigger a re-render on my app.

**EXTRA:**

This is my **meta viewport** tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

**QUESTION**

Does it make sense for the zoom event to change the `window.innerWidth` property? I mean, isn't that completely counter intuitive?

How can I avoid it, or at least, do some workaround for my app to behave the way I need?

Comment: This question ["How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) is somehow related and there does not seem to be a production-grade cross-browser solution to this problem yet. I might need to disable my `resize` event listener.